# Dompdf rendering spaces incorrectly with custom font

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

I'm using Dompdf v2.0.1 to make a report. I'm using a custom font from Google Fonts (Josefin Sans) but the spaces are rendered incorrectly.

[image]

But when rendering the page as HTML, spaces are displayed correctly.

[image]

Below I'll paste the HTML and PHP code I'm using to generate the PDF.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Relatório de atendimentos</title>
        <style>
            @page {
                margin: 16px;
                padding: 0;
            }

            body {
                font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
                font-size: .8em;
            }
            table {
                width: 100%;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border: none;
            }
            td, th {
                padding: .3em;
            }
            td {
                border: solid 1px #000;
                font-weight: 300;
            }
            .title {
                font-size: 1.2em;
                color: #FFF;
                text-align: center;
                background-color: #363435;
                border-color: #363435;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="title">Relatório detalhado de tickets</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>GERADO POR: </b> sadsadsad
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Actions\Report;

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

class GenerateReport
{
    public static function run(array $data): string
    {
        return GenerateReportString::get($data);

        $pdf = new Dompdf([
            'isRemoteEnabled' => true,
            'isJavascriptEnabled' => false,
            'dpi' => 200,
        ]);
        $pdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
        $pdf->loadHtml(
            GenerateReportString::get($data)
        );
        $pdf->render();
        return $pdf->output();
    }
}
```

I tried setting the charset to UTF-8 in the HTTP header (`Content-Type: application/pdf; charset=UTF-8`), but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a font subsetting bug in the underlying php-font-lib library, see issue [2445](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/2445). Not all fonts are impacted, but for those that are you can temporarily work around the issue by disabling subsetting.

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf(["IsFontSubsettingEnabled" => false]);
```

Note: This isn't a great solution if the font is large since it will impact the overall PDF size.